# Scope of variables in a for loop in JS

Tags: javascript, scope

Consider the following for loop in Javascript.

```
for( var i=0;i<10;i++){ }
console.log(i);
```

If i run the code, I will get 10 in the console. Why is this? How is the scope of variable 'i' available outside for loop ?

Comment: Javascript does not have block scope, it has only function level scope....

Comment: Although you have [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let) in ES6

Comment: JS Hoists all of the vars declared in a function to the starting of function, so all of them are available throughout the function. NOTE: although if they are used before their declaration in function, their value will be undefined

Comment: There is also global scope.

Answer (score 0):

In javascript, there is no block level scope prior to ES6 (with [let](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)), so any variable you declare will have a function level scope (if the declaration is inside a function) or global scope.

> JavaScript before ECMAScript 6 does not have block statement scope;
>   rather, a variable declared within a block is local to the function
>   (or global scope) that the block resides within. For example the
>   following code will log 5, because the scope of x is the function (or
>   global context) within which x is declared, not the block, which in
>   this case is an if statement.

- [Variable scope](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Grammar_and_types#Variable_scope)